# How to convert Unicode string to a TCHAR system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, unicode, wchar

I have a python (3.6) code that should pass a Unicode string to an Unreal Engine project. The Unreal Engine displays text in TEXT format which I'm not wrong is an array of Win-Api's TCHARs. I saw that on my platform the TCHAR is 2 bytes.

Here is how I encode the string on the python side:

```
by = bytes(st, 'utf-8')
```

I tried encoding and passing the string **"Hello"**. The unreal got the data ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] (each char 1 byte), and printed **"效汬o"** (it treats the "He" and "ll" as a single Unicode character).

How can I fix this?

- Should I change the encoding on the python side to always generate 2 bytes per char?
- Should I decode the result byte array on unreal to TCHAR Unicode somehow?

Comment: TCHAR is related to the Win32 API, which you should at least mention. Might need to also tag your question "windows"...

Comment: `TCHAR` is either ANSI or UTF-16. It depends on compiler defines. Probably what you really mean is that the data is an array of `wchar_t`.

Comment: How are you passing data to then engine?  ctypes?  If so, just use the `str` type directly.  ctypes knows to pass `str` as UTF-16 to functions using wchar_t.

Comment: @dav: Or ASCII, if neither `_UNICODE` nor `_MBCS` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your configuration, `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`, a character type that is unilaterally encoded using UTF-16LE on Windows.

You can encode the string using:

```
by = bytes(st, 'utf-16')
```

Comment: Works perfectly. So simple.

Comment: No, a `TCHAR` isn't UTF-16. The meaning (and fundamental type) depends on external settings, namely whether or not `_UNICODE` or `_MBCS` is defined. Details are explained in the [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings) topic.

Comment: Sure, I agree. But given the output shown in the question it was clear the settings here are Unicode.